# ZABBIX Calculated item from Postgres custom query

Tags: zabbix

Zabbix 6.0


Function:

```
last(//pgsql.custom.query["tcp://localhost:5432","zbx_monitor","pass","postgres","all_tables_stat"])
```

Key in template item:

```
pgsql.custom.query["{$PG.URI}","{$PG.USER}","{$PG.PASSWORD}","{$PG.DATABASE}","all_tables_stat"]
```

Item in template works *correctly*.

**Error**:

```
Cannot evaluate function: item "/Custom Test PostgreSQL by zbx_agent_2/pgsql.custom.query["tcp://localhost:5432","zbx_monitor","pass","postgres","all_tables_stat"]" does not exist at "last(//pgsql.custom.query["tcp://localhost:5432","zbx_monitor","pass","postgres","all_tables_stat"])".
```

How to solve it?